# reactjs 404 Error while reloading browser

Tags: reactjs, iis

I have some issues with deploying React applications on an IIS server. Once the application reloads, it will show 404 File Not Found like that.

Thank you.

[[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIH2f.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIH2f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer need to add web.config file in application path.

and need to add this content inside of web.config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```